# Php fetch data from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysqli, fetch

[image]

I'm trying to fetch data from ring_desc table the column name is get_name
here is my code:

```
$query= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM LIST l, ring_desc r where l.user_id=$cook_val 
and l.img_id=r.id");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$name = $row['get_name'];
```

When I add `$row['id']` which is column of List table it runs fine,
but when I run this with `get_name` it says:

> **Notice: Undefined variable: get_name**

Comment: Can you put the structure of the relevant table?

Comment: sure, 1 moment................

Comment: I have added the structure

Comment: try to change `mysqli_fetch_array` -> `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Comment: Try to use JOIN in your query. It is also recommended to specify fields in your `SELECT` statement unless you really need to use `SELECT *`.

Comment: Thank you all for replying the problem is solved i just change the order of table in my query  SELECT * FROM  ring_desc r, LIST l,

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$query= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT l.*,r.* FROM LIST l, ring_desc r where l.user_id=$cook_val 
and l.img_id=r.id");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT l.*,r.* FROM LIST l inner join ring_desc r on l.img_id=r.id where l.user_id=$cook_val
```

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_fetch_array - Fetchs a result row as a numeric array
so use this

```
   $name = $row[3]
```